# Earth tilt openGL c++

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on the solar system and I'm trying to get the planet Earth to rotate properly around the Sun. I can get it to orbit and rotate on its axis, but I can't get it to be tilted in the right angle, as seen in the picture below:
[image]

I can tilt my planet, but it loos like this when it goes around (it doesn't "face" the same direction)

[image]
 Any ideas what I could do? Here is my code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
//sun
glMaterialAmbientAndDiffuse(GLMaterialEnums::FRONT,GLColor<GLfloat,4>(1.5f,1.0f,0.0f));
glTranslate(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotate(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 00.0);
drawEllipsoid(10.0, 1.0, 4, 4);

//Earth
glRotate(orbit, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslate(30.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glPushMatrix();
glMaterialAmbientAndDiffuse(GLMaterialEnums::FRONT,GLColor<GLfloat,4>(0.5f,10.5f,10.5f));
glRotatef(110,0.0,23.0,110.0f); 
glRotatef(orbit2, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f);
drawPlanetGrid(5, 1, 4, 4, 1);

glRotate(30.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0);
glTranslate(orbit2, 0.0, 0.0);
glPopMatrix();
orbit += .2;

if (orbit > 360)    
{
orbit = 0;
}
orbit2 += 6.5;
if (orbit2 > 360)
{
orbit2 = 0;
}
```

Sorry the code is not commented. I am just experimenting with it.

Comment: I love the spheres :)

Comment: Thank you... I was using perfect round spheres, but I couldn't tell if they were rotating or not... so I did this to them to be able to tell if they were or not

Comment: Your essential problem is that you can't accomplish this by composing transformations (assuming the origin is the star).  If you use a rotational transformation to move the centroid of the planet, you'll cause the poles to be rotated as well.  If you tilt the planet after positioning it, the rotational transform used for tilting will move it out of the ecliptic plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship between the Sun and the Earth is not hierarchical as it is in the case of an arm and an elbow. They are independent objects. Therefore, instead of using nested matrices, you should compute the position of the Earth manually. You can do this using simple trigonometry:

```
earth_x = 30.0 * cos(orbit / 180.0 * PI)
earth_y = 30.0 * sin(orbit / 180.0 * PI)
```

After translating to this point, you can tilt the Earth using `glRotate()` in the same way you did before but this time the transformation won't be affected by the Earth's position.

In the end, your code should look like this:

```
drawTheSun();

glPushMatrix();  // enter the Earth's frame of reference
glTranslate(earth_x, earth_y, 0.0);
glRotate(110,0.0,23.0,110.0f);  // tilt however you wanna tilt
drawTheEarth();
glPopMatrix();  // exit the Earth's frame of reference
```

Comment: You should use them to translate to the Earth's frame of reference. See my edit.

Comment: man, you're super smart. I got another question that you might be able to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594194/moon-orbit-in-relation-to-sun 
Thank you, and thanks for helping me out with this one. It works!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an ancient question, but I had the same question and this was the first result.  I believe it can be done with 'nested' matrices as the OP was trying to do.

For Earth, or any planet for that matter:

```
glRotatef(inclination, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(orbit,       0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glTranslatef(            R, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(-orbit,      0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glRotatef(Tilt,        1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(orbit2,      0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
drawPlanet();
```

I used this code (with a different orientation of the coordinate system) to make a program that plots (or prints) the positions of the planets and stars. It roughly (good enough for animations) matches the output from the NASA Horizons system ([NASA Horizons web interface](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/), as well as matching other 'live' solar system diagrams on the net- [Solar System calculator](http://cosinekitty.com/solar_system.html), [In-the-Sky](https://in-the-sky.org/solarsystem.php).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).