# Moon orbit in relation to sun

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

I can get the Earth to rotate around the Sun and around its own axis, but I can't get the Moon to rotate around the Earth. (I just want it to circulate around it, I don't need to calculate gravity or anything like that.)

Here is my code:

```
double earth_x = 50.0 * cos(orbit / 180.0 * Math::Constants<double>::pi);
double earth_y = 45.0 * sin(orbit / 180.0 * Math::Constants<double>::pi);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
//sun
glMaterialAmbientAndDiffuse(GLMaterialEnums::FRONT,GLColor<GLfloat,4>(1.5f,1.0f,0.0f));
glTranslate(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotate(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 00.0);
drawEllipsoid(10.0, 1.0, 4, 4);



//Earth
glPushMatrix();
glTranslate(earth_x, earth_y, 0.0);
glMaterialAmbientAndDiffuse(GLMaterialEnums::FRONT,GLColor<GLfloat,4>(0.2f,50.0f,50.5f));
glRotatef(110,0.0,23.0,110.0f); 

glRotatef(orbit2, 0.0f, 0.0f,1.0f);
drawPlanetGrid(5, 1, 20, 20, 1.5);

glPopMatrix();

glMaterialAmbientAndDiffuse(GLMaterialEnums::FRONT,GLColor<GLfloat,4>(50.2f,50.0f,50.5f));
//Moon
glTranslate(earth_x+10, earth_y+10, 0.0);
glRotate(moonOrb, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

drawEllipsoid(1, 1, 9, 9);  

moonOrb += .5;
if (moonOrb > 360)
moonOrb = 0.0;
orbit += .9;
if (orbit > 360)    
{
    orbit = 0;
}
orbit2 += 6.5;
if (orbit2 > 360)
{
 orbit2 = 0;
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong with my code? 
As of right now I don't have texture on my objects, so that's why it's missing from the code. I am really just trying to understand how the solar system works before I make any changes to the sizes, orbit shape and things like that.

Comment: By orbit, you just mean circle, not calculate gravity and forces and such.

Comment: yes, that is correct. I just want it to circulate around my "Earth" sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you did what I recommended in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16594168/252687, all you have to do is to replicate the code once more for the Moon. As celestial objects are not rigidly bound, it's wiser to compute their orbits independently, instead of nesting their reference frames.

The earth's position is:

```
earth_x = 30.0 * cos(earth_orbit / 180.0 * PI)
earth_y = 30.0 * sin(earth_orbit / 180.0 * PI)
```

The Moon's position is:

```
moon_x = earth_x + 15.0 * cos(moon_orbit / 180.0 * PI)
moon_y = earth_y + 15.0 * sin(moon_orbit / 180.0 * PI)
```

And the code should look like this:

```
drawTheSun();

glPushMatrix();  // enter the Earth's frame of reference
glTranslate(earth_x, earth_y, 0.0);  // move to the position of the Earth
glRotate(110, 0.0, 23.0, 110.0f);  // earth-local transformations
drawTheEarth();
glPopMatrix();  // exit the Earth's frame of reference

glPushMatrix();  // enter the Moon's frame of reference
glTranslate(moon_x, moon_y, 0.0);  // move to the position of the Moon
glRotate(110, 0.0, 23.0, 110.0f);  // moon-local transformations
drawTheMoon();
glPopMatrix();  // exit the Moon's frame of reference
```

Comment: When I do this it begins moving around the Earth, but instead of rotating around it, it does more of a zig-zag. Any ideas why it would be happening? Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by zig-zag. Be sure your `moon_orbit` increments aren't too large and planet transformations aren't affecting each other.

Comment: I'm such a noob!! I had my sin and cos inverted... I got it...  Thanks man

Comment: Congrats! I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display()
{
    static int lastMs = glutGet( GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME );
    int curMs = glutGet( GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME );
    double dt = ( curMs - lastMs ) / 1000.0;
    lastMs = curMs;

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    double ar = w / h;
    gluPerspective( 60, w / h, 0.1, 100 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef( 0, 0, -20 );

    static float earth = 0;
    static float moon = 0;

    earth += 2 * dt;
    moon += 36 * dt;

    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glColor3ub( 255, 255, 0 );
        glutSolidSphere( 4, 8, 8 );

        glPushMatrix();
        {
            glRotatef( earth, 0, 0, 1 );
            glTranslatef( 10, 0, 0 );

            glColor3ub( 0, 255, 255 );
            glutSolidSphere( 1.5, 8, 8 );

            glPushMatrix();
            {
                glRotatef( moon, 0, 0, 1 );
                glTranslatef( 2, 0, 0 );

                glColor3ub( 128, 128, 128 );
                glutSolidSphere( 0.5, 8, 8 );
            }
            glPopMatrix();
        }
        glPopMatrix();
    }   
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer(int extra)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(16, timer, 0);
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```